# How would I recover a crashed ubuntu instance running in VMware workstation?

Tags: ubuntu, windows-10, virtual-machine, vmware-workstation

I was running VMware Workstation 11.0 VM on a Windows 10 (64bit) host with Ubuntu 14.04 as guest. Last night my windows crashed and I reset my windows but all new application/software I lost including my Ubuntu, there were lost.

I have important files on Ubuntu so I want to recover those files/documents, I have backup of all files in "C:\Windows.old\" directory.

Any suggestions how to repair this?

Comment: You did enable *AutoProtect*, right? Just add the VM again and it should work (given that Ubuntu doesn't freak out).

Comment: I am not aware of AutoProtect can you please explain a bit. @GiantTree

Comment: AutoProtect takes a snapshot of your whole virtual machine every time it deems necessary and allows you to be safe when your host crashes

Comment: Enable it in your VM's options

Comment: No I am not sure I had enabled AutoProtect before crashing my window 10, Any other solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Resetting windows to factory defaults may have killed your vmware workstation installation, but the disk files are probably still where they were before the reset. (E.g. on D:\vms\Ubuntu).

You should be able to install vmware workstation again, point it to those files and everything should work. Alternatively, you can mount vmware disk files in windows. You might need to add support for the filesystem though.